# Como centralizar um JFrame na tela do computador?

Tags: java, swing

Estou utilizando o GUI *builder* do NetBeans para fazer algumas coisas com Swing e gostaria de centralizar a `JFrame`, na qual esta a minha aplicação, na tela do computador. Contudo, não sei onde eu edito esta parte.

Onde fica quando o programa executa:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Onde eu quero que fique (mais ou menos) quando o programa executar:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Window#setLocationRelativeTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo-java.awt.Component-) passando o valor `null` como argumento. Segundo a documentação:

> If the component is `null`, or the `GraphicsConfiguration` associated with this component is `null`, the window is placed in the center of the screen.

Pode chamar esse método depois do `initComponents` gerado pelo NetBeans.

```
public class MinhaClasse extends JFrame {

   public MinhaClasse(){
     initComponents(); // Método gerado pelo NetBeans.
     meujFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   }
}
```

Comment: Um adendo, deve-se chamar esse método após a janela ter sido completamente construida. De preferencia, antes de setar como visivel.

Comment: Por isso chamado depois de `initComponents`.

Comment: É que eu costumo deixar pro `main` fazer isso(após estanciar a classe), por precaução.

Comment: Existe algum jeito de usar este mesmo código num método @renan?